# Does there exist an almost everywhere smooth function that does not have a local extrema at an endpoint of its domain?

Tags: calculus, functions

Does there exist a function $f:[0,\infty)\to {\mathbb{R}}$ that is smooth almost everywhere such that $(0,f(0))$ is not a local extrema?

Comment: Huh? Does $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ count?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Your function has a local max at $0$. Note OP's domain.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm silly. I meant to write $f(x) = (x+1)^2$. Here I'm assuming by local extrema he means $f\,'(x) = 0$ (as per usual) but who knows.

Comment: is $f$ assumed to be continuous?

Comment: Could you give a definition of "almost smooth".  I couldn't find one anywhere.  Do you mean differentiable except for some points?

Comment: Since @Evan’s comment furnishes the desired example, I suggest that it be written up as an answer.

Comment: I was hoping that $f'(0)=0$, but $(0,f(0))$ is neither a local minimum or a local maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can easily turn this into a smooth example. Let $h$ be a smooth function with all derivatives at $0$ equal to $0$. For example, take $h(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, $x\ne 0$, $h(0)=0$. Set $f(x)=h(x)\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: does your function $f$ have a derivative at 0?

Comment: Yes. Infinitely many derivatives! They're all $0$.

Comment: I don't understand. Since $h'(0)=0$, the product rule gives $f'(0)=h(0)(\sin(1/x))'|_{x=0}$. But why is $(\sin(1/x))'|_{x=0}$ defined?

Comment: You can't use the product rule in this setting. You have to go back to the *definition* of the derivative and use the squeeze principle, noting that $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$.

Answer (score 3):

(Comment to answer)

Let $g(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$. It is a smooth function except at $0$ (though continuous). However $(0,g(0))$ is not a local extrema (there are points as close to $0$ as you wish that take values above and below $0$).